# Css - how can i place this inner div in the center of outer div?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

How to place class `small_icons` in the center of `tpt_box` horizontally?

```
<div id="tpt_box" style="position: fixed;top:0px;left:2px;background-color: transparent;color:white;
     z-index: 999; width: 100%;">
    <div class="small_icons" style="">
      <span class="count" id="mytimer" >0</span>
      <span class="status" id="status" ></span>
      <span class="refresh" id="refresh" onclick="window.location.reload();" ></span>     
      <span class="chat" id="chat" onclick="chatme();" ></span>      
      <span class="fullscreen" id="myfullscreen" onclick="enterFullScreen();"></span>
      <span class="endcall_btn" id="disconnectcall"></span>
      <!-- Contents -->
      <span class="content_popup" id="content_popup" onclick="content_popup();" ></span>

    </div>         
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be so many possible ways to achieve the expected result, the easiest way would be

Add `style=" ...; text-align: center;"` to the outer `div`.
Add `style="display-inline: block;"` to the inner `div`.

```
<div id="tpt_box" style="position: fixed;top:0px;left:2px;background-color: transparent; color: white; z-index: 999; width: 100%; text-align: center">
    <div class="small_icons" style="display: inline-block;">
```

Comment: applied like you have mentioned

Comment: so, how do you see the inner div? at the left?

Comment: YES - inner div is always remaining in the left instead of center horizontally.

Comment: Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U2B3L/)! please check it out! Except `color: black` and `border: solid 1px #000;` is changed and added for testing purpose. Everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    #tpt_box{
     height: 300px;
     position: fixed;top:0px;left:2px;background-color: transparent;color:white;
     z-index: 999; width: 100%;

   }

   .small_icons{

      postion: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
   }
```